# Multiple renv packages (Loaded and on-disk path mismatch)

Tags: path, rstudio, renv

So when I run devtools::session_info() after opening a project in it's own specific directory and calling renv::restore() (the directory is a pulled repo pulled from github), everything runs fine except it throws the following error:

```
    [1] C:/Users/austin/R_desktop_sub/Kunch_demo_KRSA_template/renv/library/R-4.3/x86_64-w64-mingw32 
    [2] C:/Users/austin/AppData/Local/R/cache/R/renv/sandbox/R-4.3/x86_64-w64-mingw32/1e360f03
    
     P ── Loaded and on-disk path mismatch.
```

It seems that the renv from the repo has it's own instance of R, compared to what I have globally on my machine. Is this causing the path mismatch, and if so, would removing the R instance in the local repo solve this? Or would I have to rewrite the lockfile?
Neither of these versions of R are listed in my system environment PATH variables, but I have this path in the PATH variables "C:\Program Files\R\R-4.3.2\bin" Which I assume points to the R folder on-disk (or is a shallow copy)?

I really appreciate any clarity you can give on this situation
Thank you!